# Can't install GIT on a CentOS 6.0 x64

Tags: centos, git

I'm trying to install GIT by either RPM or YUM but i can't. I get the following error:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
        libcrypto.so.10 is needed by git-1.7.1-2.el6.i686
        libcurl.so.4 is needed by git-1.7.1-2.el6.i686
        libexpat.so.1 is needed by git-1.7.1-2.el6.i686
        libssl.so.10 is needed by git-1.7.1-2.el6.i686
        libz.so.1 is needed by git-1.7.1-2.el6.i686
        perl(Error) is needed by git-1.7.1-2.el6.i686
        perl(Git) is needed by git-1.7.1-2.el6.i686
        perl-Git = 1.7.1-2.el6 is needed by git-1.7.1-2.el6.i686
```

When running `yum install git`:

```
root@server [/usr/local/src]# yum install git
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.symnds.com
 * extras: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * updates: mirror.trouble-free.net
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.7.1-2.el6_0.1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.1-2.el6_0.1 for package: git-1.7.1-2.el6_0.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Git) for package: git-1.7.1-2.el6_0.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Error) for package: git-1.7.1-2.el6_0.1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: git-1.7.1-2.el6_0.1.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: perl(Error)
Error: Package: git-1.7.1-2.el6_0.1.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: perl-Git = 1.7.1-2.el6_0.1
Error: Package: git-1.7.1-2.el6_0.1.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: perl(Git)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
bandmin-1.6.1-5.noarch has missing requires of perl(bandmin.conf)
bandmin-1.6.1-5.noarch has missing requires of perl(bmversion.pl)
bandmin-1.6.1-5.noarch has missing requires of perl(services.conf)
exim-4.69-30_cpanel_maildir.x86_64 has missing requires of perl(SafeFile)
frontpage-2002-SR1.2.i386 has missing requires of libexpat.so.0
```

**Repo List:**

```
repo id                       repo name                                status
base                          CentOS-6 - Base                          5,664+355
extras                        CentOS-6 - Extras                                1
updates                       CentOS-6 - Updates                          991+51
repolist: 6,656
```

The server is running the latest WHM/cPanel.

How to fix that?

Comment: Did you try installing the missing libraries and packages?

Comment: If he is installing via yum, it should have resolve the dependencies.

@Tom, can you do a command "yum repolist" and paste in your question?

Comment: To workaround yum errors, try to use `yum shell` commands. Here's how I've upgraded **from git 1.8 to git 2.24**: https://serverfault.com/a/1045216/91648

Answer (score 17):

As you can see from [this](http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/package-clean-up-issues-229412-p2.html#post1152392) post in the cPanel forums, cPanel/WHM opts to install its own version of Perl from source so it blacklists the perl* packages that could be pulled in by yum in /etc/yum.conf.

The solution is to temporarily [ignore the excludes](http://ikawhero.blogspot.ca/2010/09/installing-git-on-centos-server-with.html) directive while yum sorts out the dependencies for Git:

```
yum install git --disableexcludes=main --skip-broken
```

Comment: worked mate +1 thnx

Answer (score 3):

It looks like while you are installing git for the first time, it is pulling from the update repo first - which has git-1.7.1-2.el6_0.1.x86_64.rpm (as opposed to git-1.7.1-2.el6.x86_64.rpm).

There are two options to approach this:

Install git from the base and disable the update repo temporarily with:

```
yum -y install git --disablerepo=updates
```

or

Apply most of the current updates with:

```
yum -y upgrade
```

And then run the git install again, so that you can satisfy your current dependencies with the updated version of git.

I suggest former approach, as you don't want to apply updates if you don't have a regression plan.

EDIT: Okay, since it can't seem to resolve the dependencies or it is going to a repo that does have those updates rpm, download the RPM from these locations:

http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/centos/6.0/updates/x86_64/RPMS/perl-Git-1.7.1-2.el6_0.1.noarch.rpm

http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/centos/6.0/os/x86_64/Packages/perl-Error-0.17015-4.el6.noarch.rpm

and then install through yum with:

```
yum localinstall perl-Error-0.17015-4.el6.noarch.rpm perl-Git-1.7.1-2.el6_0.1.noarch.rpm
```

and the try to install git again. If necessary, download git itself and install with:

```
yum localinstall perl-Error-0.17015-4.el6.noarch.rpm perl-Git-1.7.1-2.el6_0.1.noarch.rpm git-1.7.1-2.el6_0.1.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Neither worked, Still requiring perl-git and perl-error

Comment: Okay, updated response with the third option.

Comment: Installed git-Error, but can't install perl-Git, It says: `error: Failed dependencies:
        git = 1.7.1-2.el6_0.1 is needed by perl-Git-1.7.1-2.el6_0.1.noarch`

Comment: Okay, download http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/centos/6.0/updates/x86_64/RPMS/git-1.7.1-2.el6_0.1.x86_64.rpm then do yum localinstall git-1.7.1-2.el6_0.1.x86_64.rpm  perl-Git-1.7.1-2.el6_0.1.noarch.rpm

Answer (score 2):

The first group of errors you posted indicate that you were trying to rpm install a 32-but version of git. This is a 64-bit system, though.

Did you run `yum install git` ? It should have resolved your dependency chain. Clean your yum cache with `yum clean all`.

If no, you will need to install the following dependencies...

`yum install openssl libcurl expat zlib perl-Git perl-Error`

Try installing `git` via `yum install git` following that.

Comment: It does find `perl-Git` or `perl-Error`

Comment: Okay, remove the two perl packages and try to install `git` alone.

Comment: i've updated the post with what i get.

Comment: Maybe try a `yum clean all` then run `yum install git`.

Answer (score 1):

Just download and compile from source.

```
mkdir /home/sources
cd /home/sources
wget http://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-1.7.8.4.tar.gz
tar -zxf git-1.7.8.4.tar.gz
cd git-1.7.8.4
./configure
make
make install
```

Comment: Bah, we have package management for a reason, and you should only go away from package management if you have a very good reason.  "yum" not working correctly indicates a problem to be fixed, not ignored.

Comment: I'm all for compiling stuff from source *when there's a good reason*, but in this case that would be a (bad) hack, not a proper fix.

Comment: @All: For version 1.7 I had no problem for installing/updating to latest version but not possible to upgrade to 1.8.x; Then I used this method to install it with success (even like you I do not like to install without package manager)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your repositories are missing some of the additional packages needed to install GIT. Typically I install the Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux repository as well and that fixes a ton of my issues.

It can be found here:

[RHEL5](http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/4/i386/repoview/epel-release.html) or
[RHEL6](http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/repoview/epel-release.html)

Install the RHEL6 Repo and you should have access to the additional packages that you are needing.

Best if Luck

Comment: GIT is included in the base CentOS distributions, so this is not entirely accurate.