# Install a newer version of Git on CentOS 7

Tags: git, centos7

I like to enable Git "Push to Deploy" on my CentOS 7 server. Currently I only can get Git 1.8.3.1 via yum. I need a newer version.

Do I have to build it from source or is there any repo I can use? I alreay added [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) and [elrepo](http://elrepo.org/tiki/tiki-index.php) but yum still gives me Git 1.8.3.1.

Comment: "Push to deploy" means to use git hooks that get active upon a push. What functionality regarding this are you missing in the EL7 git version? I am successfully using Git 1.7.1 on EL6 for many such tasks.

Comment: @Sven Based on the need for a newer git version I'd rather say that he is referring to the Git 2.3 "Push to deploy", which allows you to push to a non-bare repository, and also have its working directory updated - https://github.com/blog/1957-git-2-3-has-been-released

Comment: andol is right, I would like to use the "push to deploy" feature that is new with Git 2.3

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You could use a **IUS repository** (https://ius.io/) as provided on Git official site [here](https://git-scm.com/download/linux) or [here](https://ius.io/setup). It contains prebuilt binaries for `x86_64`.

To do that, run (as root):

```
yum install epel-release
yum remove git
rpm -U https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm
yum install git2u
```

(`centos7` can be replaced with `centos6` or `rhel{6,7}` if you are not using CentOS).

**Note:** some users report that there is no more package called `git2u`. You can also try packages `git222` or `git224` in that case.
Note: git2u is no longer valid. You can check in github for the latest IUS Git version. https://github.com/search?q=org%3Aiusrepo+topic%3Arpm+git&s=updated&type=repositories
It worked for me using "sudo yum install git236".

Another option would be to use another RPM repository (`i386` & `x86_64`):

```
sudo yum -y install https://packages.endpointdev.com/rhel/7/os/x86_64/endpoint-repo.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum install git
```

**Note 2**: as reported @alaindeseine in comments there is an issue accessing https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm. In that case use https://repo.ius.io/ius-release-el7.rpm

Comment: Definitely the method I would use, since you get a well-maintained RPM installed rather than whatever your build tools created.

Comment: Just want note that it might not be secure to use 3rd party repos. Here is a [blog post](https://linux-audit.com/missing-packages-do-not-trust-external-repositories/) dealing with that issue.

Comment: @robsch I completely agree with that, and I never will use external repos if required packages would be provided in standard/ofiicial repos. As always, it's a trade off subject. Anyway, we always should follow the "think twice before you do" strategy.

Comment: I got `curl: (7) Failed to connect to centos7.iuscommunity.org port 443: Connection timed out` on `Amazon Linux AMI` Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: @VanTho IUS site may be down, please see my addition in my answer below

Comment: https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ currently gives me a certificate error, because the certificate is for laura.legalaccessplans.com I'd avoid it ius.io at least doesn't give certificate errors.

Comment: It seems that the new instruction for setting up ius is: https://ius.io/setup. Also there is no package called `git2u` anymore. The new name should be `git224`: `yum install git224` works for me.

Comment: Use `rpm --erase --nodeps git` instead of `yum remove git` or *golang* pkg will be removed because it depends on *git*.

Comment: Note that due to [endpoint rebranding](https://www.endpointdev.com/blog/2021/10/moving-to-endpointdev-dot-com/), the endpoint repo link should be changed to `https://packages.endpointdev.com/rhel/7/os/x86_64/endpoint-repo.x86_64.rpm`.

Comment: Works for me, but need to replace ``rpm -U https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm `` by ``yum install https://repo.ius.io/ius-release-el7.rpm``

Comment: With `yum search git2` I found `git236`.

Answer (score 19):

I have this approach for CentOS 7.2:

```
rpm -U http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/7/git/x86_64/wandisco-git-release-7-2.noarch.rpm \
    && yum install -y git
```

At the moment I have `2.10.0` GIT version.

Or for CentOS 7.1 the same path but `wandisco-git-release-7-1.noarch.rpm`.

You may inspect available releases http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/7/git/x86_64/

Answer (score 15):

Building from source is quite straightforward. Digital Ocean has a [nice guide on building Git from source on CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-git-on-centos-7). Place the resulting binary in /usr/local/bin/ on your CentOS 7 system (which, by default, is included in your $PATH) and you're good to go.

Of course you would prefer packages/using the repo, however given your situation I would not hesitate building it myself.

For general information; Push to Deploy was introduced in [Git 2.3.0](https://github.com/blog/1957-git-2-3-has-been-released). Make sure to use this version or above.

Answer (score 14):

What is working for me for CentOS 7:

```
yum install \
https://repo.ius.io/ius-release-el7.rpm \
https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

yum remove git
yum install git236
```

Ref:

- https://ius.io/setup

Comment: As of June 2022 the last line should be `yum install git236`.

Comment: @Yerke Thanks, verified here: https://repo.ius.io/7/x86_64/packages/g/.

Comment: What does git236 stand for? Is it for version 2.3.6?

Answer (score 8):

Red Hat maintains a software collection for Git 2.9:

https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-git29/

This is the easiest and safest way to get Git 2.x on CentOS.

Comment: This is nice but only for x86_64 basearch currently

Comment: and how to make scl binaries system wide defaults

Answer (score 5):

These days, a proper git package (not `git2u`) is available on [endpoint](https://packages.endpointdev.com/):

```
yum -y install https://packages.endpointdev.com/rhel/7/os/x86_64/endpoint-repo.x86_64.rpm
yum -y install git
```

Answer (score 3):

The "Inline with Upstream Stable" (https://ius.io/) repo looks pretty good to me.

It has git 2.x rpms which play nicely with the rpm conflicts system.

You can find git rpms here:

https://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/7/x86_64/repoview/letter_g.group.html

I found the SCL (Software Collections) way to be more cumbersome.  They're 
very careful not to interfere with the user who doesn't use them.  A bit over careful in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps for those who can't use non standard/external repositories on Centos 7.6.

These steps are also suitable to be placed in a Dockerfile (if you don't want to upgrade Centos version)

```
yum update -y
yum install wget which zlib-devel perl-devel -y
wget https://github.com/git/git/archive/v2.26.2.tar.gz -O /tmp/git.tar.gz
cd /tmp && tar -zxf git.tar.gz
cd /tmp/git-2.26.2
make configure
# ./configure # to overwrite your existing git and YUM managed git locations
./configure --prefix=/usr/local # standard way
make install
whereis git
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If somebody is looking for an ansible script running on RHEL7:

```
    - name: Remove build-in GIT
      yum:
        name: git
        state: absent
      become: true      

    - name: Download epel-release
      get_url:
        url: https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
        dest: ~/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

    - name: Install epel-release 
      yum:
        name: epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
        state: present
      become: true

    - name: Download uis-release
      get_url:
        url: https://repo.ius.io/ius-release-el7.rpm
        dest: ~/ius-release-el7.rpm

    - name: Install uis-release
      yum:
        name: ius-release-el7.rpm
        state: present
      become: true

    - name: Install git 224
      yum:
        name: git224.x86_64
        state: present
      become: true
```

If you are looking for some other git version, check available versions after installing `uis-release` using

```
sudo yum list git*
```

Comment: You can give the URL directly to the yum module. You don't need to download it in a separate play.

Answer (score 0):

On RHEL 7.8, I got conflict errors when trying to `yum upgrade git` (from version 1.8 to 2.24):

> Error: git224-core conflicts with git-1.8.3.1-23.el7_8.x86_64
> Error: git224 conflicts with git-1.8.3.1-23.el7_8.x86_64
> Error: git224-perl-Git conflicts with perl-Git-1.8.3.1-23.el7_8.noarch
> You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem

To workaround this I used yum shell commands:

```
$ sudo yum shell
> erase git
> install git224
> run
  ...

  Removed:
    git.x86_64 0:1.8.3.1-23.el7_8                                                                     

  Dependency Removed:
    perl-Git.noarch 0:1.8.3.1-23.el7_8                                                                

  Installed:
    git224.x86_64 0:2.24.3-1.el7.ius                                                                  

  Dependency Installed:
    git224-core.x86_64 0:2.24.3-1.el7.ius            
    git224-core-doc.noarch 0:2.24.3-1.el7.ius       
    git224-perl-Git.noarch 0:2.24.3-1.el7.ius       

> quit

$ git --version
git version 2.24.3
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an official, made by RedHat, package with **git 2.27** available for both **x86_64** and **ARM64**  available in [Software Collections](https://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/overview?extIdCarryOver=true&sc_cid=701f2000001OH7EAAW).

You can install it with:

```
yum install -y centos-release-scl-rh
yum install -y rh-git227-git
```

Note that by design it is installed under `/opt` and is not in your PATH by default.

You can easily make it the preferred git binary f.e. with a symlink:

```
ln -s /opt/rh/rh-git227/root/usr/bin/git /usr/local/bin/git
```

**UPDATE**: oups, sorry, while this package is a worth consideration way to go, it’s not that easy to use software collections. You have to enable the collection, I will update the answer later.

Comment: source /opt/rh/rh-git227/enable

Answer (score 0):

#### Here is the Steps to upgrade git on CentOS 7 which I have followed

```
$ sudo yum list git*

Installed Packages
git.x86_64                                                                                            1.8.3.1-20.el7                                                                                     @base  
Available Packages  
git.x86_64          1.8.3.1-25.el7_9     updates 
git-svn.x86_64      1.8.3.1-25.el7_9     updates  
git236.x86_64       2.36.6-1.el7.ius     ius    
git236-all.noarch   2.36.6-1.el7.ius     ius    
git236-core.x86_64  2.36.6-1.el7.ius     ius
```

Choose from above git pkg list e.g git236

```
$ sudo yum shell
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
> erase git
> install git236
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: linux.mirrors.es.net
 * epel: mirrors.sonic.net
 * extras: centos-distro.cavecreek.net
 * updates: mirror.team-cymru.com
> run
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.8.3.1-20.el7 will be erased
--> Processing Dependency: git = 1.8.3.1-20.el7 for package: perl-Git-1.8.3.1-20.el7.noarch
---> Package git236.x86_64 0:2.36.6-1.el7.ius will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 2.36.6-1.el7.ius for package: git236-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: git-core-doc = 2.36.6-1.el7.ius for package: git236-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: git-core = 2.36.6-1.el7.ius for package: git236-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Git::I18N) for package: git236-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Git) for package: git236-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git236-core.x86_64 0:2.36.6-1.el7.ius will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre2-8.so.0()(64bit) for package: git236-core-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.x86_64
---> Package git236-core-doc.noarch 0:2.36.6-1.el7.ius will be installed
---> Package git236-perl-Git.noarch 0:2.36.6-1.el7.ius will be installed
---> Package perl-Git.noarch 0:1.8.3.1-20.el7 will be erased
--> Running transaction check
---> Package pcre2.x86_64 0:10.23-2.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                               Arch                                         Version                                                   Repository                                   Size
================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 git236                                                x86_64                                       2.36.6-1.el7.ius                                          ius                                          71 k
Removing:
 git                                                   x86_64                                       1.8.3.1-20.el7                                            @base                                        22 M
Installing for dependencies:
 git236-core                                           x86_64                                       2.36.6-1.el7.ius                                          ius                                         6.9 M
 git236-core-doc                                       noarch                                       2.36.6-1.el7.ius                                          ius                                         2.8 M
 git236-perl-Git                                       noarch                                       2.36.6-1.el7.ius                                          ius                                          46 k
 pcre2                                                 x86_64                                       10.23-2.el7                                               base                                        201 k
Removing for dependencies:
 perl-Git                                              noarch                                       1.8.3.1-20.el7                                            @base                                        57 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package (+4 Dependent packages)
Remove   1 Package (+1 Dependent package)

Total download size: 9.9 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
warning: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/ius/packages/git236-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 4b274df2: NOKEY                                      ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA 
Public key for git236-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.x86_64.rpm is not installed
(1/5): git236-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                |  71 kB  00:00:00     
(2/5): git236-core-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                           | 6.9 MB  00:00:00     
(3/5): git236-core-doc-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.noarch.rpm                                                                                                                                       | 2.8 MB  00:00:00     
(4/5): git236-perl-Git-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.noarch.rpm                                                                                                                                       |  46 kB  00:00:00     
(5/5): pcre2-10.23-2.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                      | 201 kB  00:00:00     
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                                                                                                           9.2 MB/s | 9.9 MB  00:00:01     
Retrieving key from file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-IUS-7
Importing GPG key 0x4B274DF2:
 Userid     : "IUS (7) <dev@ius.io>"
 Fingerprint: c958 7a09 a11f d706 4f0c a0f4 e558 0725 4b27 4df2
 Package    : ius-release-2-1.el7.ius.noarch (installed)
 From       : /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-IUS-7
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : pcre2-10.23-2.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                     1/7 
  Installing : git236-core-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.x86_64                                                                                                                                                          2/7 
  Installing : git236-core-doc-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.noarch                                                                                                                                                      3/7 
  Installing : git236-perl-Git-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.noarch                                                                                                                                                      4/7 
  Installing : git236-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.x86_64                                                                                                                                                               5/7 
  Erasing    : perl-Git-1.8.3.1-20.el7.noarch                                                                                                                                                               6/7 
  Erasing    : git-1.8.3.1-20.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                    7/7 
  Verifying  : pcre2-10.23-2.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                     1/7 
  Verifying  : git236-core-doc-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.noarch                                                                                                                                                      2/7 
  Verifying  : git236-core-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.x86_64                                                                                                                                                          3/7 
  Verifying  : git236-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.x86_64                                                                                                                                                               4/7 
  Verifying  : git236-perl-Git-2.36.6-1.el7.ius.noarch                                                                                                                                                      5/7 
  Verifying  : git-1.8.3.1-20.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                    6/7 
  Verifying  : perl-Git-1.8.3.1-20.el7.noarch                                                                                                                                                               7/7 

Removed:
  git.x86_64 0:1.8.3.1-20.el7                                                                                                                                                                                   

Dependency Removed:
  perl-Git.noarch 0:1.8.3.1-20.el7                                                                                                                                                                              

Installed:
  git236.x86_64 0:2.36.6-1.el7.ius                                                                                                                                                                              

Dependency Installed:
  git236-core.x86_64 0:2.36.6-1.el7.ius               git236-core-doc.noarch 0:2.36.6-1.el7.ius               git236-perl-Git.noarch 0:2.36.6-1.el7.ius               pcre2.x86_64 0:10.23-2.el7              

Finished Transaction
> quit
Leaving Shell
```

Check/validate git version after upgrade.

```
$ git --version
git version 2.36.6
```